# Test if network folder exists

Tags: java, windows

How can I test if a network folder exists in Windows using Java?

For example, if there was a network folder named "Groups" and it listed the groups a user was in, how could I see if the network folder "Groups\Admin" exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as with any other directory. Just add a double slash before:

```
new File("//Groups/Admin").exists()
```

Comment: Would there be a delay in using this code as in the computer having to search "//Groups" for "/Admin"? (As in more than if it were not a network folder)

Comment: Delay relative to what?

Comment: If there's a network delay there's a network delay. I'm not sure what your question is.